# Getting null value when casting string to Double in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to cast string value for column `LOW` to double but getting null values in dataframe.

[image: Dataframe df2 contains string value for column LOW]

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df3 = df2.withColumn("LOW",df2["LOW"].cast(DoubleType()))
df3.printSchema()
df3.show()
```

[image: schema and resulting DF df3 containing null values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the commas that separate the groups of three digits (US number formatting) before casting into double. Try with this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df3 = df2.withColumn("LOW", F.regexp_replace("LOW", ",", "").cast("double"))
```